# Output "linux shell" vs "php system()" - sorting

Tags: php, linux, output

Let's execute command:

```
# zcat -f /var/log/remotelog*|grep -e "10\.0\.1\.15"|grep -e "7,35)"|sort -k 1M -k 2r|tail -n 250 3>&1
```

Got output like this:

```
Apr  3 11:38:49 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link on(operational)
Apr  3 11:38:35 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link off(operational)
Apr  3 11:06:20 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link on(operational)
Apr  3 11:06:16 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link off(operational)
Apr  3 11:06:15 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link on(operational)
Apr  3 11:05:41 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link off(operational)
Apr  2 17:54:02 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link on(operational)
Apr  2 17:53:31 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link off(operational)
Apr  1 02:02:27 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: Success upgrade ONU(7,35)
Apr  1 02:02:23 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: Success Download-OS ONU(7,35)
Mar 31 15:03:51 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link on(operational)
Mar 31 15:03:41 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link off(operational)
```

Very nice...

But then i do it this way:

```
<?php
$e = "zcat -f /var/log/remotelog*|grep -e \"10\.0\.1\.15\"|grep -e \"7,35)\"|sort -k 1M -k 2r|tail -n 250 3>&1";
system($e, $ret);
echo $ret ;
?>
```

And i got this output:

```
Mar 31 15:03:51 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link on(operational)
Mar 31 15:03:41 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link off(operational)
Apr  3 11:38:49 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link on(operational)
Apr  3 11:38:35 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link off(operational)
Apr  3 11:06:20 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link on(operational)
Apr  3 11:06:16 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link off(operational)
Apr  3 11:06:15 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link on(operational)
Apr  3 11:05:41 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link off(operational)
Apr  2 17:54:02 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link on(operational)
Apr  2 17:53:31 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: ONU(7,35) eth port 1 link off(operational)
Apr  1 02:02:27 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: Success upgrade ONU(7,35)
Apr  1 02:02:23 10.0.1.15 GPOND[927]: Success Download-OS ONU(7,35)
```

Why? I don't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the second one (through PHP) is the "correct" output.

As the list is first sorted by month name and the month name is dependent on the locale settings, I suspect that the locale settings (LC_* environment variables) are different in command line and in PHP, which affects the output of the sort.

Comment: You're right. Now it seems so obvious - i've adde env LC_ALL=pl_PL before sort and now it works like a charm. Thx!